# Function argument type followed by *&

Tags: c++, parameters, casting

I have some code written by someone else in which some functions take arguments whose data types are followed by a *&. I'm used to functions taking one or the other, e.g. taking a "double *" or a "double &" but not both. It would have thought they would just cancel out.

Here's an example, and this is all from their code which supposedly works:

In a header file there's a function declared as:

```
void someClass::foo(const unsigned int*& ubuff);
```

Then in my main file, there's a pointer to some UINTs declared and initialized as:

```
unsigned int* pbuff = new UINT[n];
```

Then, the function someClass::foo is called as:

```
foo(pbuff);
```

When I compile, I get the error "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int *' to 'const unsigned int *&'". If I change my function call to the following, it compiles ok:

```
foo((const unsigned int *&)(pbuff));
```

So, my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of the *&? I.e., how is that different from * or & by themselves, and why do they not just cancel themselves out? And what does that make the function foo expect? An address? A value? The address of an address? It's confusing.
2. Is the fix of simply casting a "unsigned int*" to a "const unsigned int*&" ok or do I need to do something else?

Just another quick example, and this is from completely within a cpp file distributed by someone else, so I assume this compiled for them. They have a function call as

```
klabels = new int[sz];
EnforceLabelConnectivity(klabels, m_width, m_height, nlabels, numlabels, double(sz)/double(STEP*STEP));
```

When I try to build, I get an error "'SLIC::EnforceLabelConnectivity' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'const int *&'".

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried casting to a (const unsigned int *), and that did not work (wouldn't build). In the end, I had to fully cast to a (const unsigned int *&) in the foo function example in my original post. Hope this helps. Thanks.

As an aside, the reason I did not go the route of making pbuff const from the beginning in my main code is that it is passed to another function later on which does modify it, so I don't think it would work to have it made const when declared.

Answer (score 3):

For a type T, `T *&` means "a reference to a pointer to a T." The calling function should pass a pointer to a T. As to the const modifier, try `foo((const unsigned int *)pBuff);` or else declare pBuff to be a pointer to a const int to start with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification on *&, I get it now, but I'm still not sure what's the best way for me to modify this code to get it working. 

I added another example at the end of my original post. Could you have a look? This is completely from within their code, so presumably this built for the code's authors, but it won't build for me (VS2008). On what type of compiler/ system would this be ok? 

What's the best option for me to get this working? Change the function itself? Cast parameters when I call it? Or change declaration of the variables? Thanks again.

Comment: For the first problem try `foo((const unsigned int *)(pbuff));`. For the second (assuming that klabels is declared as a `int *`), you can do the same thing. However, since the method apparently expects a pointer to a _constant_ int, you should probably initialize the array contents before making the call.

Comment: I tried the casting you recommended for pbuff in function foo, and it does not work, I get "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int *' to 'const unsigned int *&'".

Answer (score 0):

1. Pointers and references are really differents, but using a  reference to a pointer is kind of useless.
2. This is not ok, pbuff is not const that's why your code doesn't compile. Use a const pbuff or change your prototype, casting like this is really ugly

Comment: A reference to a pointer is hardly useless. It makes the pointer modifiable in the caller from within the called function. Usually not what you want, but when you do, it's quite useful.