# Pointer to a reference parameter

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function argument type followed by *&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054484/function-argument-type-followed-by)

I am looking at someone else's code right now and saw an unusual (atleast for me) function declaration syntax. Is the following valid C++ syntax?

```
bool Foo::Bar(Frame *&ptoframe, int msToBlock)
{
    ....
}
```

I think the developer is trying to declare a pointer to a reference.

thanks for the help

Comment: Look up the spiral rule. It greatly aids in reading type declarations. That is, in fact, a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Types are read from right to left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. Read the syntax from right to left: it's read *reference to a pointer*. This is important if you wish to change the pointer being passed to the function. The pointer is effectively passed by reference just like any other parameter.

Here's a pretty example:

```
void no_change(int * ptr) {
    ptr = 0;
}

void change_ptr(int *& ptr) {
    ptr = 0;
}

int main() {

    int *x;

    change_ptr(x);

}
```

The value of any pointer passed to `change_ptr` will be changed because we are passing it by reference.

Note, however that the value of the object to which a pointer points can still be changed through the `no_change` function (i.e `*ptr = new int`). This syntax is applying only to the actual pointer, not its pointed-to object.

Comment: Did you mean `right to left` and not `left to right`?

Answer (score 4):

No, the first function parameter is a *reference to a pointer*. Sometimes you want to change someone else's pointer... To wit:

```
void change_my_char(char & c)    { c = 'x';     }

void pimp_my_pointer(void * & p) { p = nullptr; }

int main() {
  char x;
  void * y;
  change_my_char(x);
  pimp_my_pointer(y);
}
```

Comment: Is it sad that I read `pimp_my_pointer` as `p-imp my pointer` (as in p-impl)?

Comment: @chris: It might be quite in-character, so don't feel too bad :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's a pointer that's being passed by reference. This allows the callee to change the value of a caller's pointer.